# paypal api permission third party authorization

Tags: php, api, permissions, paypal

I am developing a third party authorization with Permissions API.

I get the token successfully with the `RequestPermissions` and `GetAccessToken` API, but then I don't know how to use `TransactionSearch` and `GetTransactionDetails` with the token.

Before I used `GetTransactionDetails` just with API UserName, API Password, and API Signature, but now when I use the third party, I don't know how to use the token I got with permissions API. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check page 20-22 of the Permissions API guide https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_permissions.pdf

Comment: thank you very much! but I still don't know how to use other paypal api such as GetTransactionDetails, when permissioned，can you give some demo of php, looking forwoard you reply...

Comment: once you generate the signature using your token, this is how you do it using curl:
curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp \
-H "X-PP-AUTHORIZATION: token=RmhmSyiCTsFasl7HxkH29I53W7CyEpLD2IvSk5jrEseRaBdGIrFSLA,signature=2bcPYGvnxrK6IJdsRBJG6ZEEU3ug=,timeStamp=1363306745" \
-d "METHOD=GetBalance&VERSION=98.0".
you don't need to pass your api credentials.

Comment: Thank you so patiently answer my question...I'm using php,but how to generate the signature ,the document says PayPal provides SDKs that you can use to generate authentication header signatures for Java,
PHP, and .NET...I can't find which one to generate signature with sdk file , looking forwoard your reply...thanks again!

Comment: I got it, it has the class in permission-sdk...thank you still

Answer (score 0):

Hey BlueSky you can use the `OauthSignature.getAuthHeader()` method from `paypal_base.jar` to create the `X-PP-AUTHORIZATION`